# Reading Windows file summary properties (title, subject, author) in Java

Tags: java, windows, file, summary, author

If you right-click on a file in Windows and select **Properties**, you can manage some properties in de **Summary** tab, such as Title, Subject and Author, like in this example:

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to read these properties using **Java**. Is there a library for this? Is this even possible?
Thanks in advance!

Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That information is stored in an NTFS [Alternate Data Stream](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763) named "♣SummaryInformation" - not sure if Java supports teh reading of ADS data via the colon notation.

**Update:** Apparently [this should work:](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5372760)

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt:\u2663SummaryInformation");
```

You'll have to figure out the format yourself.

Comment: do you have a reference URL for the name of this special stream? The links you provided are great but don't seem to cover this special ADS.

Comment: @Andreas_D: I just added the metadata to a file and listed its streams using a tool I found here: http://www.flexhex.com/docs/articles/alternate-streams.phtml

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 it may work, but until then you have to use a native dll, to get that information.