# How to get file summary information with Java/Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, summary

i'am trying to get the summary information from file with JAVA and I can't found anything. I tried with `org.apache.poi.hpsf.*` .

I need Author, Subject, Comments, Keywords and Title.

```
       File rep = new File("C:\\Cry_ReportERP006.rpt");


        /* Read a test document <em>doc</em> into a POI filesystem. */
        final POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(rep));
        final DirectoryEntry dir = poifs.getRoot();
        DocumentEntry dsiEntry = null;
        try
        {
            dsiEntry = (DocumentEntry) dir.getEntry(DocumentSummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            /*
             * A missing document summary information stream is not an error
             * and therefore silently ignored here.
             */
        }

        /*
         * If there is a document summry information stream, read it from
         * the POI filesystem.
         */
        if (dsiEntry != null)
        {
            final DocumentInputStream dis = new DocumentInputStream(dsiEntry);
            final PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(dis);
            final DocumentSummaryInformation dsi = new DocumentSummaryInformation(ps);
            final SummaryInformation si = new SummaryInformation(ps);


            /* Execute the get... methods. */
            System.out.println(si.getAuthor());
```

Comment: Why don't you post the code, even if its not working it will still help with the answer?

Comment: So you're talking about MS Office files, correct?

Comment: Now I post the code. No about MS Office files, I am talking about in general files.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? It looks about correct to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the sample code here- [**Appache POI how to**](http://poi.apache.org/hpsf/how-to.html)

In brief, you can a listener `MyPOIFSReaderListener`:

```
    SummaryInformation si = (SummaryInformation)
             PropertySetFactory.create(event.getStream());
    String title = si.getTitle();
    String Author= si.getLastAuthor();
    ......
```

and register it as :

```
    POIFSReader r = new POIFSReader();
    r.registerListener(new MyPOIFSReaderListener(),
                   "\005SummaryInformation");
    r.read(new FileInputStream(filename));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll read these. I have also read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096973/reading-windows-file-summary-properties-title-subject-author-in-java , but I didn't understand.

Comment: Good. If this is helpful, please don't forget to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the POI overview at http://poi.apache.org/overview.html, there are more types of file parsers.
The following examples extract the Author/Creator from 2003 office files:

```java
public static String parseOLE2FileAuthor(File file) {
    String author=null;
    try {

        FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        POIFSFileSystem poifs = new POIFSFileSystem(stream);
        DirectoryEntry dir = poifs.getRoot();
        DocumentEntry siEntry =      (DocumentEntry)dir.getEntry(SummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
        DocumentInputStream dis = new DocumentInputStream(siEntry);
        PropertySet ps = new PropertySet(dis);
        SummaryInformation si = new SummaryInformation(ps);

        author=si.getAuthor();
        stream.close();
  
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
    } catch (NoPropertySetStreamException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
    } catch (MarkUnsupportedException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
    } catch (UnexpectedPropertySetTypeException ex) {
        ex.getStackTrace();
    }
    return author;
}
```

For DOCX, PPTX, and XSLX, the POI has specialized classes.
Example for `.docx` file:

```java
public static String parseDOCX(File file){
    String author=null;
    FileInputStream stream;
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(file);
        XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(stream);
        CoreProperties props = docx.getProperties().getCoreProperties();
        author=props.getCreator();
        stream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
     

    return author;
}
```

For PPTX, use `XMLSlideShow` or `XMLWorkbook` instead of `XMLDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

for 2003 office files, you can use classes inherited from POIDocument. here is an example for doc file:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(in);
author = doc.getSummaryInformation().getAuthor();
```

and HSLFSlideShowImpl for ppt,
HSSFWorkbook for xls,
HDGFDiagram for vsd.

there are many other file information within the SummaryInformation class.

for 2007 or above office file, see the answer of @Dragos Catalin Trieanu