# Get uploading file author in Java

Tags: java, excel, spring, apache-poi, portlet

I'm trying to find a way to get the Author of the Excel file that is uploaded. Once the Upload button is clicked, all I can see is the 'byte[] contents' and I'm confused to find a way to find the author of the uploaded file. I was getting the NoPropertySetStreamException when I run the below code.

```
public static Map<String, Boolean> validateFileSize(MultipartActionRequest request,
        List<String> appCaseId) {
    
    if (PortletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        Map<String, List<MultipartFile>> multipartFiles;

        multipartFiles = request.getMultiFileMap();

        if (multipartFiles != null && !multipartFiles.isEmpty()) {
            for ( List<MultipartFile> multipartFilesList : multipartFiles.values()) {
            for ( MultipartFile item : multipartFilesList) { 
                   byte[] contents;
                    try {
                        contents = item.getBytes();

                    try {
                        SummaryInformation si = (SummaryInformation)
                                 PropertySetFactory.create(item.getInputStream());
                        si.getLastAuthor();
                    } catch (NoPropertySetStreamException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (MarkUnsupportedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        
                    }
```

Comment: Here is an older but possibly quite helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861054/how-to-get-file-summary-information-with-java-apache-poi

Comment: What kind of `Excel` file is uploaded? `PropertySetFactory` is for the old binary `BIFF`-format (`*.xls`) only. The current `Offiice Open XML`-Format (`*.xlsx`) has `POIXMLProperties`.

Comment: @Alex - I'm trying to upload *.xlsx files

Answer (score 1):

There are two mainly different kinds of `Microsoft Office` files. The old binary `OLE2` files (`*.xls`, `*.doc`, `*.ppt`, ...) and the newer `Office Open XML` (`OOXML`) files (`*.xlsx`, `*.docx`, `*.pptx`, ...).

For `OLE2` the properties are in `PropertySet` which can be got via `PropertySetFactory`. But you need using it correctly. The `InputStream` used in `PropertySetFactory.create(java.io.InputStream stream)` is not meant to be the `InputStream` of the whole file. Instad it would must be a `DocumentInputStream`. Better approach would be using `PropertySet.create(DirectoryEntry dir, java.lang.String name)`. See example below.

For `OOXML` the properties are in `PackageProperties` which can be got from the `OPCPackage`.

To determine whether a file is `OLE2` or `OOXML`, [FileMagic](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/poifs/filesystem/FileMagic.html) can be used. `FileMagic.valueOf(java.io.InputStream inp)` returns `FileMagic.OLE2` or `FileMagic.OOXML` respectively.

The following example shows how to get the author out of the `PropertySet` of `OLE2`files and out of the `PackageProperties` of `OOXML` files. This shoud work for each kind of `Microsoft Office` which `apache poi` supports.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.FileMagic;

import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySetFactory;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet;
import org.apache.poi.hpsf.SummaryInformation;

import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageProperties;

public class GetAuthor {

 static String getAuthor(InputStream is) throws Exception {

  String author = null;

System.out.println(FileMagic.valueOf(is));
  if (FileMagic.valueOf(is) == FileMagic.OLE2) {
   POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(is);
   PropertySet props = PropertySetFactory.create(fs.getRoot(), SummaryInformation.DEFAULT_STREAM_NAME);
   if (props instanceof SummaryInformation) {
    SummaryInformation sumInf = (SummaryInformation) props;
    author = sumInf.getAuthor();
   } 
  } else if(FileMagic.valueOf(is) == FileMagic.OOXML) {
   OPCPackage pckg = OPCPackage.open(is);
   PackageProperties props = pckg.getPackageProperties();
   author =  props.getCreatorProperty().get();
  }

  return author;

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String author = null;

  InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xls"));
  author = getAuthor(is);
System.out.println(author);
  is.close();

  is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("./Excel.xlsx"));
  author = getAuthor(is);
System.out.println(author);
  is.close();

 }
}
```