# Grabbing Windows File Properties (author, date, subject etc.) with Java

Tags: java, python, windows, file, properties

I am trying to grab Windows file properties from a file such as author, date, subject etc. I have try using summary information and and `FileNotFound` exception comes up. How could I do this. I have searched for a while and found nothing that works. If the solution isn't possible in Java, could it possible in C or Python? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: what other attributes are covered in etc?

Comment: I would to be able to grab anything in the details section, (from file properties in windows 7), so path, tags, comments, anything in there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096973/reading-windows-file-summary-properties-title-subject-author-in-java

Comment: I have tried that but this throws the file not found exception: test.txt:\u2663SummaryInformation

Comment: Or does the number affect it? (2663) in the previous comment?

Comment: look at this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html . This might be of your help.

Comment: I have tried the tutorial before and it only brings up information about the file (date created, title), not information of the actual file, like where it came from (author, tags etc).

Comment: I have been looking more into the summary information, the question that I have is how would you read from it? I realize that's probably the correct direction, but I am unsure how to proceed.