# Windows File Properties with Java

Tags: java, windows, properties, utf-8, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to grab Windows file properties using Java. The information that I am trying to get is the information under details, such as: author, date created, tags, folder path, etc. I have tried to use the answer from: [Reading Windows file summary properties (title, subject, author) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096973/reading-windows-file-summary-properties-title-subject-author-in-java).

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("test.txt:\u2663SummaryInformation");
```

Yet, when I try this, it gives me File Not Found Exception. I have made sure that the file that I am trying to open exists. I have also made sure that Eclipse is in UTF-8 mode (for the club "\u2663" before "SummaryInformation"). I have also tried it out of UTF-8 mode. I am unsure why I am getting the File Not Found Exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: File name "test.txt:\u2663SummaryInformation" doesn't sound right for Windows file name. Try some simple file like "c:\test.txt"

Comment: that was the example from the other page. I create a file, then check to see if its a file. Then use that path with :\u2663SummaryInformation

Comment: Are you using Java 7?  If so, Files.getAttribute(Path, String) should do the trick

Comment: I understand that `\u2663` will be parsed to correspondent unicode character by Java **but** the character `:` is illegal in Windows for a file name.

Comment: Why do you want to do it all in java? You can try to find dll which you will load using Java Native Access library.

Comment: Okay, because the ':' is an illegal character for Windows, what is the format I should use?