# Get the title attribute from an mp3 file

Tags: java, properties, mp3

**Problem**
I want to display file properties like title and author of an mp3 from:

[image: mp3 information]

I have tried using http://javamusictag.sourceforge.net/ but it doesnt actually get the information input into the properties details (see picture).
How do I get that information such as the 'Test Song' by 'John Smith'?
Of course I have the file available on java:

```
File file = new File(path);
```

Thanks in anticipation! If you need more info just ask.

ps:
I looked at this and it doesn't work or I don't understand it ([summary question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096973/reading-windows-file-summary-properties-title-subject-author-in-java))

Comment: I believe that's part of the file format.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how do I access those parts of the format?

Comment: You'll have to look at the file format and figure out which bytes give this information. There might already be a Java library that does this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure

Comment: Any ideas how to do this? What about this: AudioFormat.getProperty("Title");?

Comment: How would one get the title of a file? `String a = (String)Files.getAttribute(path, "Title", LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS);`

Comment: I used [jaudiotagger](http://www.jthink.net/jaudiotagger/) before and it seemed to work well.

Answer (score 0):

The spec for this is at [id3.org](http://id3.org/Developer%20Information).  Version 2.3 is probably sufficient for most of the files you will ever look at...