# Get the description of a File in Java

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I want to write a Java code, to get the description of any file located on a Windows server. The *Description* has to be the same as mentioned in the file after right clicking on it and then clicking on *Properties*.

For example, following is the file: `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` Right click on it, and click on *Properties*. The description is *"Google Chrome"*.

Please help.

UPDATED:

Even if someone can give me a method to derive the data of the "Description" field shown in the Windows Task Manager for a particular ProcessID, it will help me.

Comment: I think this will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824027/get-the-metadata-of-a-file

Comment: Some more inputs from here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096973/reading-windows-file-summary-properties-title-subject-author-in-java

Comment: What is your JDK  version?

Comment: @Beri my JDK version is 1.6

Comment: @AbhijeetKharkar  If only you could upgrade to JDK7 you could use benefits of java.nio.file.Files util, sources: http://www.javabeat.net/obtaining-and-modifying-the-metadata-of-the-files-in-java-7-nio-2/. But I have never used thm for reading file descriptions, those are not standard file data.

Comment: @Beri i have updated my question just now. If you may help me even with that, it would solve my problem.

Comment: @AbhijeetKharkar in that you could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java . Name of process can be added when you start it. It is not directly connected with file itself, in linux at least. I don't know much about windows.

Comment: @Beri Thanks anyways. I am not able to find any link to achieve what I have mentioned in the question. I have began believing that the thing which I want is not actually possible.

Comment: @AbhijeetKharkar it might be easy to do in linux enviroment, as you have ready command line for that. But windows is not so develop friendly :) Good luxk with your quest for answers:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/tooltipInfo.bat) - it will `return the right-click-> details` of a file .
You can start it from java like this

```
try
{
    String line=null;
    String filePath="\"YOUR FILE PATH\"";
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("toolTipInfo.bat "+filePath);
    String processDesc="";
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));       
    while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.contains("File description:"))
            processDesc=line.split(":")[1].trim();
    }
    input.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{

}
```

Comment: excellent answer. It addressed my problem aptly. Thanks a ton :D. Just made minor changes just to filter out File Description.